# How to convert multiple apk files into a unified bundle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, apk, android-app-bundle

My Android app uses a custom native library (written in C++) that I compile for each of the architectures `armeabi-v7a`, `arm64-v8a`, `x86` and `x86_64`. The earliest version of Android that supports 64-bit native libraries (`arm64-v8a` / `x86_64`) is API level 21 but with the 32-bit native libraries (`armeabi-v7a` / `x86`) I'm able to support devices down to Android API level 16.

Due to those differing API levels and because the compiled libraries get quite big I create a specific apk file for each of those architectures. So, eventually I have 4 different apk files which enables my app to run on pretty much every Android device down to API level 16. That approach works and is documented [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks). My `build.gradle` file that builds those apk files looks as follows:

```
android
{
  ...

  defaultConfig
  {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 29
    ...
  }

  flavorDimensions "abi"
  productFlavors
  {
    "ARM7"
    {
      dimension "abi"
      ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
      versionCode 160000 + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
      versionNameSuffix "-arm32"
    }

    "ARM8"
    {
      dimension "abi"
      ndk.abiFilters 'arm64-v8a'
      minSdkVersion 21
      versionCode 210000 + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
      versionNameSuffix "-arm64"
    }

    "x86"
    {
      dimension "abi"
      ndk.abiFilters 'x86'
      versionCode 160000 + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
      versionNameSuffix "-x86"
    }

    "x86-64"
    {
      dimension "abi"
      ndk.abiFilters 'x86_64'
      minSdkVersion 21
      versionCode 210000 + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
      versionNameSuffix "-x64"
    }
  }

  ...
}
```

Now, Google pushes the new Android Bundle format and the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle) currently states

> Important: In the second half of 2021, new apps will be required to publish with the Android App Bundle on Google Play. New apps larger than 150 MB must use either Play Feature Delivery or Play Asset Delivery.

So, at some point I will have to convert my multi-apk approach to that new Android Bundle format but I'm essentially clueless how this is supposed to work. While each of my apk file contains its own manifest with its own version number and `minSdkVersion` an Android Bundle contains one unified manifest.

How would I be able to create an Android Bundle that eventually has the same effect as my 4 existing apk files?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is an easier way of achieving what you already have- splits-on-abi (see https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits). This method handles the versionCode and so forth for you.

As noted on that page- it's better to use app bundles for this purpose now. App bundles have two main purposes- to minify(/optimize) downloads, and to allow for dynamic modules. The first bit makes it so that Google Play essentially takes your huge app-bundle containing everything, and makes a smaller apk containing only what is needed for the particular device that is asking. It is only this minimal apk that is downloaded to the device.

So, to summarize: You upload *one* big app bundle to Google Play containing everything for all devices. Google Play then builds minimal apks containing only what is needed, and downloads only those to device. Technically speaking, Google play creates an `.apks` which is downloaded, this is essentially a zip file with multiple .apk files, following this format: [image: app bundle apks format] but that is mostly just an implementation detail you don't need to worry about.

You can simulate and try out how app bundles work (`.aab` format) with the bundletool (https://github.com/google/bundletool/releases) which according to Google *is* what Google Play is using to handle app bundle files.

Also, you can drop the flavors. Those will only get in the way now.

Comment: I understand the part of the Android App Bundle. That is the goal, to move away from .apk files to bundles. What is unclear to me is that the `minSdkVersion` of all .apk files that are eventually generated from the bundle is 16, even for the ones with the 64-bit native library (verified using bundletool). However, the minimum API level of Android that supports 64-bit is 21, not 16. Unless there is a Google Play mechanism that prevents rolling out 64-bit .apk files on anything lower than API level 21 there is a problem. So, the question comes down to: Is there such a mechanism?

Comment: It is the responsibility of the devices to report which abi's they support, and only those are sent down across the wire.

Comment: This seems to me to be one of those things that just works. You don't need to manually handle minSdkVersion based on abi's (or any other resource). The device will specify whatever it supports, and those things are sent down. I believe that's including limitations that comes from the platform, or version of the platform.

I think you should probably try bundles first, without any special handling. Just everything by default, and see if it works like you'd want. I'm pretty sure you're trying to solve an issue that isn't really there.

Comment: You might be right, Google Play somehow needs to handle this itself. I don't see any options for myself regarding `minSdkVersion`. I'm not quite ready to upload and test the bundle yet which is why I decided to ask this question. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You could use closed alpha tracks on Google Play to let you test it without publishing it.

Alternatively, you can use the bundletool cli to test this all on your local machine. `.apk`  and `.aab` are both just simple zip files- so you can generate stuff with gradle, run it through bundletool, then inspect output `.apks` as a zip file to see what actually ends up on device